# How to update a column in a table based on the result of a external function?

Tags: sql, oracle, function

I'm running into a situation where I received a external function from 3rd party, FUNCT(a1,a2,a3, ZZZ). This function accepts values for a1, a2, a3 and returns a number ZZZ.

I also have similar table structure, column1, column2, column3, Amount. I would like to match the table value of column1 to a1, column2 to a2, column3 to a3 and read the output of ZZZ and update into the Amount column in the table. I see go about cursor. Please help how it can be updated.

Thanks in advance.

## EDIT

(Copied from OP's comment on answer below)

I received a function not procedure. I was told to call the function and update. here is the code I tried running into the issue.

```
DECLARE
  pass varchar2(100);
  func_amt number;
BEGIN
  update table yt
    set yt.amount = func_amt
    where XYXFUNC(yt.a1,yt.a2, yt.a3,yt.a4,yt.5, pass , func_amt );
END;
```

Comment: A function written as FUNCT(a1, a2, a3, ZZZ) doesn't accept values a1, a2, a3 and return value ZZZ. A function written like that accepts FOUR values, a1, a2, a3 **AND** ZZZ, and returns a number FUNCT(a1, a2, a3, ZZZ). That is, the whole expression `FUNCT(a1, a2, a3, ZZZ)` is a number, the return value of the function, given the values a1, a2, a3, ZZZ. So - please go back and clarify your question. Beyond that, all you will need is a simple `update` statement (no cursor needed).

Comment: Looking at the code you put into a comment on an answer (don't do that - edit your answer to add additional information, don't use comments for that) I still think you'll need to use a wrapper function. First, you can't call a function with output parameters from an SQL statement and use the output value in SQL. Second, it appears that your function might return a BOOLEAN. BOOLEAN's are only useful in PL/SQL - Oracle does not recognize the BOOLEAN type in SQL. If you can provide the definition of your function - what parameters it takes, and what its return type is - perhaps I could help more.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that what you've got is defined as

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE FUNCT(a1  IN  VARCHAR2,
                                  a2  IN  VARCHAR2,
                                  a3  IN  VARCHAR2,
                                  ZZZ OUT NUMBER)
AS
  -- ...whatever...
END FUNCT;
```

A PROCEDURE, such as the one you've been given, cannot be called directly from SQL. Only FUNCTIONS, which return a value via the RETURN statement, can be called from SQL.

However, all is not lost. What you need is a wrapper function which calls your third party procedure, passing the appropriate arguments, captures the returned value, and then uses the RETURN statement to return the value to the caller. If you define the following function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION WRAPPER_FUNC(a1  IN  VARCHAR2,
                                        a2  IN  VARCHAR2,
                                        a3  IN  VARCHAR2)
  RETURN NUMBER
AS
  ZZZ  NUMBER;
BEGIN
  FUNCT(a1, a2, a3, ZZZ);

  RETURN ZZZ;
END WRAPPER_FUNC;
```

you can then use `WRAPPER_FUNC` from an SQL statement as:

```
UPDATE YOUR_TABLE yt
  SET yt.AMOUNT = WRAPPER_FUNC(yt.COLUMN1, yt.COLUMN2, yt.COLUMN3)
```

Add any `WHERE` clause you need to the `UPDATE` statement and you should be good to go.

Comment: Tank you for reply. I received a function not procedure. I was told to call the function and update. here is the code I tried running into the issue.     DECLARE
  pass varchar2(100);
  func_amt number;
BEGIN
update table yt set yt.amount 
= func_amt where XYXFUNC(yt.a1,yt.a2,
yt.a3,yt.a4,yt.5,
 pass ,  func_amt  );

END;

Comment: Please **edit your question** using the `edit` button just below the question tags, and include information about how this function is defined. In other words, how all the parameters and the return type are defined, because as it is we're just guessing. Thanks.